# Optimization of Select Case - long time iteration for 150k+ lines of data

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing some macros to automate some tasks and analyze data.
One of the things i noticed testing my programme was the time it takes to process all the data. I know that i have a large quantity of data but i wanted to know if there's something i can do with my code to increase the performance of my programme.
Right now i have 150k+ lines of data and this process take ages. Is there something i can do with my code?

```
Option Explicit

Sub x() 

    Dim lin_ori As Variant

    lin_ori = 2

    Sheets("MVIN_MVOU").Cells(1, 13) = "Process Layer"


    Do While Sheets("MVIN_MVOU").Cells(lin_ori, 1) <> ""

         fnd = Application.Match(Worksheets("MVIN_MVOU").Cells(lin_ori, 6), Worksheets("StepArea").Columns(3), 0)

       If Not IsError(fnd) Then      'a match was found

            Sheets("MVIN_MVOU").Cells(lin_ori, 13) = Sheets("StepArea").Cells(fnd, 2)

        End If

    lin_ori = lin_ori + 1


    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This question may be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key to speeding this up will be to use [memory-based arrays](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/).

```
Option Explicit

Sub xx()
    Dim mvinmvouWS As Worksheet
    Set mvinmvouWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MVIN_MVOU")

    '--- move all the data into a memory-based array
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim stepArea As Variant
    Dim stepAreaRange As Range
    Dim stepAreaWS As Worksheet
    Set stepAreaWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StepArea")
    lastRow = stepAreaWS.Cells(stepAreaWS.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Set stepAreaRange = stepAreaWS.Range("C1").Resize(lastRow, 2)
    stepArea = stepAreaRange.Value

    '--- move all the data into a memory-based array
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim data As Variant
    lastRow = mvinmvouWS.Cells(mvinmvouWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataRange = mvinmvouWS.Range("A2").Resize(lastRow, 13)
    data = dataRange.Value
    data(1, 13) = "Process Layer"

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
        Dim index As Long
        index = FindInArray(stepArea, data(i, 6))
        If index <> -1 Then
            data(i, 13) = stepArea(index, 2)
        End If
    Next i

    '--- now put the results back to the worksheet
    dataRange.Value = data

End Sub

Private Function FindInArray(ByRef inArray As Variant, ByVal findWhat As Variant) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    FindInArray = -1
    For i = LBound(inArray, 1) To UBound(inArray, 1)
        If inArray(i, 1) = findWhat Then
            FindInArray = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Hello PeterT, thank you very much. I am learning VBA by myself from scratch and i found very usefull the link you shared. Thanks!
Right now the code is returning another column than the one i want. I'm trying to understand what is wrong.
I found that the array has the last column (4) of the sheet steparea. 
I'm digging in to it to understand.
Thanks a lot for sharing the link :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now it's working as i want it. Just changed a range and the place i want it to search in array.
Thank you a lot :)

```
Sub cola_process_layer_MVINMVOU()

Dim mvinmvouWS As Worksheet
Set mvinmvouWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MVIN_MVOU")
Dim stepAreaWS As Worksheet
Set stepAreaWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StepArea")

'--- move all the data into a memory-based array
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim stepArea As Variant
Dim stepAreaRange As Range

Dim dataRange As Range
Dim data As Variant

lastRow = stepAreaWS.Cells(stepAreaWS.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set stepAreaRange = stepAreaWS.Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, 4)
stepArea = stepAreaRange.Value

'--- move all the data into a memory-based array

lastRow = mvinmvouWS.Cells(mvinmvouWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set dataRange = mvinmvouWS.Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, 13)
data = dataRange.Value
data(1, 13) = "Process Layer"

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
    Dim index As Long
    index = FindInArray(stepArea, data(i, 12))
    If index <> -1 Then
        data(i, 13) = stepArea(index, 2)
    End If
Next i

'--- now put the results back to the worksheet
dataRange.Value = data


End Sub

Private Function FindInArray(ByRef inArray As Variant, ByVal findWhat As Variant) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    FindInArray = -1
    For i = LBound(inArray, 1) To UBound(inArray, 1)
        If inArray(i, 1) = findWhat Then
            FindInArray = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```